# Getting word timestamps for TTS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech, google-speech-to-text-api

I have a text in japanese that I'm turning into an mp3 with the Google Cloud Text to Speech functionality.

I also want to have word timestamps for the mp3 that gets returned by Google.

Google Speech to Text offers this functionality but when I submit the files I get from TTS to STT, the result is not always good.

What is the best way to also get word timestamps for the TTS mp3?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Speech-to-Text it's a ML based service, so it's expected that the results are not always as "good" as you may expect them, it has it's limitations.

What I could suggest is to take a look at their relevant documentation about this topic like the [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices), the [guide](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-time-offsets) and the basics [page](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics#time-offsets) that talk about it. Additionally, you could take a look at the issues within their issue tracker platform, like for example this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/147938978) for additional information on it and even if you find a reproducible issue within the service you can publish it there, so their team can be aware of it.